# [Java Dates]Using an particular format to add days

Tags: java, string, date

Today I wanted to ask for a somewhat efficient way to convert `custom formatted selectors to seconds`.

If I input '5d, 6h' it should output => [x number of seconds]
where the selectors can be any number `> 999`,and be supported for `minutes,seconds, hours, days, and years, where the preceding character is the selector, y for years, h for hours, and etc.`. Another example is `9d 4s`, which still outputs `[x number of seconds]`. The two "selector" strings are stored in an array. Thanks so much!

Comment: you are welcome - any code to share?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I do not have any, as I am asking about a good way to tackle it. I can write it myself, just trying to wrap my head around how to do it.

Comment: so if input contains `h` use selector1 else use selector2 ?

Comment: No, use both. I would calculate both by adding them together. For example,

Input 1 => 5h
Input 2 => 2m
Output => 18120

@ScaryWombat

Comment: How would *YOU* do it manually? Write the code the same way you would do it.

Comment: You cannot convert years to seconds without any date context.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is confusing, there are a couple classes and a standard string format that may be close to what you want

Java provides two classes to represent a span of time unattached to the timeline.

- `Duration` (days-hours-minutes-seconds)
- `Period` (years-months-days)

Both classes can parse and generate strings in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format of P[n]Y[n]M[n]DT[n]H[n]M[n]S. The `P` marks the beginning and `T` separates the y-m-d from the h-m-s portions. So five days and 6 hours is `P5DT6H`.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "P5DT6H" );
```

Going the other direction.

```
String output = d.toString();
```

> P5DT6H

You may interrogate values by calling various methods, with more methods added in Java 9.

If you want total number seconds in entire duration:

```
long totalSeconds = d.getSeconds() ;
```

Already covered many times on Stack Overflow, so search for more discussion and examples. And please search Stack Overflow more thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an Open source library MgntUtils in java that answers in part to this requirement. It contains a static method `parsingStringToTimeInterval(String value)` this method parses a string that is expected to hold some time interval value - a numeric value with optional time unit suffix. For example, string "38s" will be parsed as 38 seconds, "24m" - 24 minutes "4h" - 4 hours, "3d" - 3 days and "45" as 45 milliseconds. Supported suffixes are "s" for seconds, "m" for minutes, "h" for hours, and "d" for days. String without suffix is considered to hold a value in milliseconds. Suffixes are case insensitive. If provided String contains an unsupported suffix or holds negative numeric value or zero or holds a non-numeric value - then IllegalArgumentException is thrown. This method returns TimeInterval class - a class also defined in this library. Essentially, it holds two properties with relevant getters and setters: long "value" and java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit. But in addition to getters and setters this class has methods toMillis(), toSeconds(), toMinutes(), toHours() toDays(). Those methods return long vlaue in specified time scale (The same way as corresponding methods in class java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

This method may be very useful for parsing time interval properties such as timeouts or waiting periods from configuration files. It eliminates unneeded calculations from different time scales to milliseconds back and forth. Consider that you have a methodInvokingInterval property that you need to set for 5 days. So in order to set the milliseconds value you will need to calculate that 5 days is 432000000 milliseconds (obviously not an impossible task but annoying and error prone) and then anyone else who sees the value 432000000 will have to calculate it back to 5 days which is frustrating. But using this method you will have a property value set to "5d" and invoking the code

```
long seconds = TextUtils.parsingStringToTimeInterval("5d").toSeconds();
```

will solve your conversion problem. Obviously, this is not overly complex feature, but it could add simplicity and clarity in your configuration files and save some frustration and "stupid" miscalculation into milliseconds bugs. Here is the link to the article that describes the MgntUtils library as well as where to get it: [MgntUtils](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/)